# Appending row in container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a code which dynamically creates rows.
The problem is when I click on button it adds row after the already present row. but Now div with id dynamic contains two rows and so if I click now button it will add two rows. If I use ('#dynamic').html() then it grabs columns but if it is done so it violates the indentation because it will not add the div with class row.
Please any body can tell me the solution to problem?

```js
$(function() {

  $("#button1").click(function() {

    $("#main-row").after($('#dynamic').html());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="above">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-1">No.</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">Name of Item</div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">Quanity</div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">Price</div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"><span class="btn"></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="dynamic">
    <div class="row padding-3 " id="main-row">
      <div class="col-sm-1  ">1</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2  ">
        <select class="container-fluid">
                    <option value="1">Computer</option>
                    <option value="2">Mobile</option>
                    <option value="3">LCD</option>
                    <option value="4">Keyboard</option>
                    <option value="5">Mouse</option>
                </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 "><input class="container-fluid" type="number" name="name" value="" /></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 "><input type="text" name="text" value="" /></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 "><a href="#" class="btn-block background-color">-</a></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="button1">Add Row</button>
</section>
```

Comment: Please, specify what you want when the user click on add row button

Comment: When the user click on Add row button the new row should be added below the row already present

Comment: The problem here is i am not able to add one row against every one button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(function() {
   $("#button1").click(function() {
      $('#dynamic').append($("#main-row").clone().removeAttr('id'));
   });
});
```